# formula in google sheet to count number of different objects?

Tags: google-sheets, count

I have a Google spreadsheet with a column that looks like this:

Each cell is dropdown list containing Fruits = [Apple,Orange,Pineapple,Papaya,Cherry,Strawberry]

### S.NO | Fruits

1. ```
   Apple
   ```
2. ```
   Orange
   ```
3. ```
   Pineapple
   ```
4. ```
   Papaya
   ```
5. ```
   Cherry
   ```
6. ```
   Strawberry
   ```
7. ```
   Apple
   ```
8. ```
   Orange
   ```
9. ```
   Cherry
   ```

**I want to count how many types of fruits are there.** *(Google sheet formula)*

- Apple, Orange and Cherry occurring twice.
- There are 6 different types of fruits in column.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly and assuming the fruits are in the range A2:A10, you should be able to use

```
=countunique(A2:A10)
```

Change range to suit and see if that helps?

---

### REFERENCE

- [Countunique()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093405?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(COUNTUNIQUE(LOWER(A1:A)))
```